# Slime Reproduction

Tags: soul-harvester

I got the following upgrade:

> Slime Reproduction - Periodically create a free slime

How does this work?  If random, what are the odds of it triggering?  If periodic, how often does it activate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One slime is generated for free once every 10 minutes.

Comment: Actually, I think the price stays the same.  Mine just went from 41 to 42 and the price did not change.

Comment: @Batophobia you are correct. I forced the function to activate using the console and didn't notice any increase in price.